# Tem como substituir comandos por variaveis no python?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estou tendo uma duvida, tem como guardar comandos em variaveis? Por exemplo:
X = while
X(True):

Assim eu poderia facilitar algumas coisas em alguns scripts, ou meio que tentar "criar" uma propria linguagem, espero que alguem possa me ajudar! :-)

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer, nem qual é o objetivo.

Comment: Eu estou querendo substituir comandos como o while por variaveis, por exemplo se eu quiser usar a variavel x como se fosse while

Comment: Beleza, Caio! Deu pra entender o que você quer nesse caso específico, mas vai ficar mais fácil te ajudar se você puder esclarecer qual o objetivo final. É criar uma linguagem baseada em Python? Com qual finalidade?

Comment: No começo era mais por curiosidade, mas agora eu tou pensando se eu poderia fazer uma "linguagem de programação" no python para eu facilitar os meus scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode guardar funções:

```
def minha_funcao(x):
    while True:
        x += 1
        print(x)
        if x % 5 == 0:
            break

minha_variavel_func = minha_funcao
minha_variavel_func(2)  # Executa minha_funcao com 2 como argumento x
```

Se couber em uma linha, você também pode usar uma lambda:

```
minha_lambda = lambda: print(*[i for i in range(4)])
minha_lambda()  # Printa "0 1 2 3"
```

Comment: Acho que lambda não caberia neste contexto analisando conceitualmente.

Comment: Se o que OP está buscando é uma forma de criar "atalhos" de uma linha em Python, o lambda cabe sim, mesmo não resolvendo exatamente o que ele perguntou.

Comment: @hdiogenes Não é só porque é de uma linha de código que se usa lambda. Uma função poderia ser definida com `def` em uma linha sem problemas, sem ferir a semântica do código. Lambda define uma relação entre entrada/saída. Usá-la pode até gerar o resultado esperado, mas não significa que deve ser feito.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Onde está escrito que 'lambda define uma relação entre entrada e saída'? No tutorial oficial do Python está escrito que "Funções Lambda podem ser usadas em qualquer lugar que objetos de função sejam necessários." Ou seja: é um recurso tão válido quanto um `def`. Por outro lado, eu acho que dizer que "não caberia neste contexto analisando conceitualmente" é muito subjetivo, e acaba criticando a resposta sem acrescentar nenhuma alternativa útil. https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o que você está tentando é criar uma **macro**, recurso que o Python não possui. Você pode tentar usar a [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy), uma biblioteca que implementa isso, mas, ao que parece, de uma forma bem complicada (requer manipulação da árvore de sintaxe do Python).

Se você quer criar uma espécie de DSL (Domain-Specific Language - Linguagem de Domínio Específico), é mais fácil. Python terá algumas limitações para isso, mas dependendo até onde você quer chegar, também fornece ferramentas, desde o uso de lambdas e decorators, até metaclasses, módulo inspect, etc.

Outra opção é buscar uma linguagem que tenha o recurso de macros nativo, como LISP ou [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html).

Comment: A resposta contém uma possível solução para o problema, logo não vejo porque deva ser postada como comentário. Além disso, não "se baseia inteiramente em um link externo", contém outras informações que podem ser úteis a quem perguntou, como por exemplo o nome do recurso que ele está procurando utilizar.

Comment: @hdiogenes me lembro de um comando chamado `doskey` do Win, você até podia substituir um comando pelo outro e automatizar seus macros ;). De qualquer forma, também seria interessante você acrescentar um pequeno exemplo pratico de como utilizar esta biblioteca.